# I lost my project and my key in android studio what to do?

Tags: android, code-signing, decompiling

Well there was an accident on my computer with it I lost my project and my key to my application. How can I decompile the application and sign with new key?

Comment: Why would you need to decompile?  Didn't you use offsite source control?  As for the key-  if it isn't a play store app, no problem.  If it is, you need to contact Google.

Comment: unfortunately without keystore you can't sign and publish another apk

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, you can retrieve source with some external tools like [javadecompilers.com (explained there)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

However for your key, you will have to create a [new application in the store unfortunately, using a new key (explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023955/lost-the-private-key-for-signing-android-apk-can-app-be-released-to-android-mar). There's no way around if you don't have it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the .apk, it is actually just a zipped file. For example with 7zip you can right click on the apk file and "extract files".

You will then need to have a new key and sign it.

Only problem i see is if the app was already released, you have to use same account, or else maybe the store will assume you publish someone else code (not sure about that)