# How to update compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from the APK without recompile the app?

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, apk, playback

I have several old applications that I made when I was a child, distributed to the play store, they are old and the APKs dont target android 13 so new users cant download them form the play store and I didn't keep the sources code of thoses apps, I can only download the APKs from google play dev console portal, so how can I update compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from the APK without recompile the app, from the apk to redistribute it to the play store ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I lost my project and my key in android studio what to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301285/i-lost-my-project-and-my-key-in-android-studio-what-to-do)

Comment: You can try to decompile them using [apktool](https://apktool.org) and decompile only resources (using `--no-src` flag). Then you can modify AndoridManifest.xml and afterwards recompile the APK, sign (`apksigner` from Android SDK) and test it. But I don't think this will work. When upgrading the targetAPI some old code will stop working so code changes will become necessary.